# PHP: Why the output is 0?

Tags: php, sql, output

im new programmer in php and now im coding a simple admin panel to train my self.
heres the code :

```
$title= 'information';
$stm=connect()->prepare("select count(title) as count from posts where title='?'");
$stm->bindValue(1,$title);
$stm->execute();
$c=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($c);`
```

**ps: i have 3 titles in my db that have information 3 ,, so it should print count = 3**

Comment: It will print what you need after you understand that `'?'` is __not__ a placeholder.

Comment: @u_mulder , i think u understand what i want , so can u help  me to fix the problem?

Comment: I think @u_mulder helped you already. The rest is for you :)

Comment: oh, now i understand XD, thanks @u_mulder